# Vuejs cant clear the result from previous ajax

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to make instant request to DB on keyup. The problem is: I cannot clear the results from previous ajax requests, even when I clear the array which contains it, when I type faster it doesn't work.

The second (smaller :D) problem is that i have to make nested loops to make it work.

I am trying many hours to solve these problems ...

[Click to see an image](https://ibb.co/cOdODk)

Component 1: HTML

```
   <input v-model="invoice_number" type="text" name="invoice_number" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Invoice number" @keyup="max_invoice_number" required>
```

Component 1: javascript

```
 max_invoice_number: function() {

        axios.get('/max_invoice_number/' + this.invoice_number)
        .then(response => this.max_invoice_response.push({ 
           info: response.data

       }));

        Event.$emit('max_invoice_response', this.max_invoice_response);
    },
```

Component 2 HTML

```
<div v-for="a in max_invoice_response" class="bg-success col-xs-12">
            <div v-for="b in a">{{b.info}}</div>
        </div>
```

Component 2 Javascript

```
data(){
        return{ 

            ref_numbers: [],
            max_invoice_response: []
        }
    },

    created: function(){

        Event.$on('max_invoice_response', function(response) {  this.clear; this.max_invoice_response.push(response); }.bind(this));

    },

    methods: {
        clear: function() {
            this.max_invoice_response.splice(0);
        }

    },
}
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting parentheses on `this.clear` in your created method? (should be `this.clear()`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is not that :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok apart from the missing parentheses, so assuming the clear method is called and the array in component 2 is emptied.

I component 1 every time you make an AJAX call, you store the response data in `this.max_invoice_response` (on component 1). The next step is that you emit the event with `this.max_invoice_response` as payload. This field contains **all** responses you've received so far.

So on handling the event in component 2 you receive all responses as well. While you do clear the array, it still pushes all responses into the `this.max_invoice_response` of component 2. So you'll need to either clear component 1 as well, or just overwrite the data you've stored.

Be careful though! HTTP responses are handled async. Since you trigger one every key up, the response for the second letter might arrive earlier than the response for the first letter.

Comment: Thank you for trieng to help me, but it is not from that I had that line on component 1 but i deleted it by mistake when I coppied here. Here you can see the code https://github.com/iliyan940/euromedic_v2/tree/master/resources/assets/js/components

Comment: I see, better update your questions so other are aware as well.

If you type slowly (one keyup every 5 seconds), does the same bug occur?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Debounce was the function i needed.
Here is my code if someone is in the same situation.

```
 max_invoice_number: _.debounce(function() {

         this.max_invoice_response = [];

         axios.get('/max_invoice_number/' + this.invoice_number)
         .then(response => this.max_invoice_response.push({ 
           info: response.data

       }));

         Event.$emit('max_invoice_response', this.max_invoice_response);
     },300),
```